# How can I further prevent my Fiddle Leaf Fig plant from growing slanted?

Tags: houseplants

As my plant grows, it slants forward. It is getting taller and I'm assuming that this is why, but is their a way to prevent this? Or a way to get it straight by using some type of item?

[image: plant1]

[image: plant2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This plant is growing towards the light.  Some solutions:

- easiest, rotate the plant pot a quarter turn every week
- stake it
- take it out of the pot, trim off the roots on the side it is leaning towards and repot straight.  Of course it will lean again so....

Providing more light and rotating the plant will give the best results with least work.

Comment: The first answer is the absolute best!  Don't stake it unless you want wimpy stems and have to always stake this plant.  Right now it is turned so those leaves will be changing direction soon, I'd do a quarter turn back so those rotations aren't 180 degrees of work.  And Kevinsky's third solution although absolutely viable is just silly when you have a movable pot.  Great, simple, straight forward answer, Kevinsky.  I am working to emulate you guys honest!

Comment: Love the composition of your photograph with the violin in the background!  Cute!!

Comment: @stormy Well, thank you very much :)